# Zapier javascript error: Cannot read property 'indexOf'

Tags: javascript, zapier

## First things first :)

I LOVE Zapier and I am not a properly schooled coder, but i do have basic experience in a few languages.

## My problem

I'm running into a problem in "code by zapier (javascript)". Hopefully this is easy to fix/ workaround. I have a really easy script that changes a date format send by Woocommerce event on plugin:

```
var Raw = input.DatumRuw;
var n = Raw.indexOf(",");

if (n > 0) {
    var ready = Raw.substr(n+1); // => 00-00-0000
    var ready = ready.substr(0,11); // => 00-00-0000;
} else {
      var ready = Raw.substr(0,10); // => 00-00-0000;
}

output = [{datumEersteLes: ready}];
```

However not in all cases DatumRuw is set. Therefor I'm running into the following error message (I think):

*Code: TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined theFunction (eval at  (/var/task/index.js:52:23), :13:12) eval (eval at  (/var/task/index.js:52:23), :34:20) Domain. (/var/task/ind...*

## My questions

Is my assumption correct?
Should I check whether the variable exists and than run the script?
How do I properly do this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What is your assumption? Reading the error message, it says that `Raw` is `undefined` ...

Comment: Yes you should check 
if(Raw){
  var n = Raw.indexOf(",");
  // then your corresponding code
}